# SQL Dynamic ASC and DESC

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have the following SQL statement where order by clause is passed dynamically .
How can I pass 'order by asc and desc' dynamically to SQL?

```
SELECT table1.prod_id,table2.prod_name from table1 left outer join table2
              ON table1.prod1 = table2.prod_id 
              ORDER BY CASE WHEN :odb = 1 THEN prod_id END
```

I would like pass `order by asc or desc` to above SQL dynamically,

how can I do this?

Comment: The `order by` doesn't make sense. It will always order by a constant value regardless of the value of `:odb` (either the value `1` or the value `null`) - thus it is not really "ordering" at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have multiple case statements. So not sure how to pass the asc or desc to sql or function dynamically.

Comment: If the column is numeric you could use something like `column_name * -1` for a descending sort which could be made dynamic. But again: your current example will **not** sort anything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If this is the case how to dynamically pass `order by` parameter and `asc` and `desc`?

Comment: Just to clear the confusion, @Polppan, when you write `ORDER BY 1`, the `1` means "the first column". But when you write `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END`, the `1` does not mean first column anymore, it is simply the literal value `1`, like @a_horse_with_no_name states. When you do expressions in the `ORDER BY` you cannot use the shortcut of using column numbers but must name the columns (or column aliases.)

Comment: @KimBergHansen I have corrected my question. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do solutions like @TonyAndrews by manipulating numeric or data values. For `VARCHAR2` an alternative to dynamic SQL could be to have two expressions:

```
order by
   case when :sorting='ASC' then col1 end ASC,
   case when :sorting='DESC' then col1 end DESC
```

When `:sorting` has the value `'ASC'` the result of that `ORDER BY` becomes like if it had been:

```
order by
   col1 ASC,
   NULL DESC
```

When `:sorting` has the value `'DESC'` the result of that `ORDER BY` becomes like if it had been:

```
order by
   NULL ASC,
   col1 DESC
```

One downside to this method is that those cases where the optimizer can skip a SORT operation because there is an index involved that makes the data already sorted like desired, that will not happen when using the CASE method like this. This will mandate a sorting operation no matter what.

Comment: Kim, When I append col1 with a dynamic value as :col1 then sorting doesn't work, however if I use with actual column name sorting does work without a hitch.

Comment: Or perhaps I need a case statement for each column?

Comment: @Polppan Your bind variable `:col1` cannot contain a column name, that won't work. If you do `ORDER BY :col1` and the value of `:col1` is `MYCOLUMN`, then it will be as if you wrote `ORDER BY 'MYCOLUMN'` which is ordering by a constant value, not by the column MYCOLUMN. Then you either need a case statement for each column or you build your SQL statement dynamically - that is build the SQL as a string and use IF/CASE logic to append the desired order in the SQL string before executing it. How that is done depends on your environment - PL/SQL, .NET, Java, or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

If the column you are sorting by is numeric then you could do this:

```
order by case when :dir='ASC' then numcol ELSE -numcol END
```

For a date column you could do:

```
order by case when :dir='ASC' then (datecol - date '1901-01-01') 
              else (date '4000-12-31' - datecol) end
```

I can't think of a sensible way for a VARCHAR2 column, other than using dynamic SQL to construct the query (which would work for any data type of course).

Answer (score 4):

This will work for all data types:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT table.*
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prod_id) sort_asc
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prod_id DESC) sort_desc
        FROM   table)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN :odb = 1 THEN sort_asc ELSE sort_desc END
```

Comment: Jeffrey, if I have a SQL with joins, how can I do this?

Comment: Just put them in place of `table`.

Comment: I have updated my question with my join SQL(although it is sample) how can I modify my SQL to incorporate your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Just make `table` into a subquery based on your SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly, you can not do it dynamically, because Oracle builds the execution plan based on these `ASC` and `DESC` keywords.
What you can do is changing the ORDER BY clause to this:

```
SELECT * table 
 ORDER BY :order_param
```

And pass `:odb` value to `:order_param` if you want to order it by `ASC` (bigger `:odb` values would be least in order) or `1/:odb` if you want to order by `DESC` (bigger `:odb` values would produce smaller `1/:odb` values and would appear on top of the result).
And, as always, you can generate the query dynamically in a stored procedure:

```
IF ... THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * table ORDER BY CASE WHEN :odb = 1 THEN 1 END ASC';
ELSE 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * table ORDER BY CASE WHEN :odb = 1 THEN 1 END DESC';
END IF;
```

Comment: I think your latter part of answer is sensible to me, more control and former part I didn't quite understand.