# Is it possible to pass parameter as keyword in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, keyword, oracle19c

In Oracle 19c, is it possible to do something like this:

```sql
select * from my_table
order by my_col :dir
```

Where `:dir` is `ASC` or `DESC`. I know I can use case, but I'm looking for something easier.

Comment: No.  You ca only do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: For a numeric sort column you might be able to multiply it by either 1 or -1 in the `order by` clause. For strings it gets more complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Dynamic ASC and DESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015623/sql-dynamic-asc-and-desc)

Comment: No. Allowing this would be an invitation to SQL injection - consider if `:DIR` was bound to something like `ASC; DROP TABLE Students;`...

Answer (score -1):

Possible? Yes.

```
SQL> select * From dept order by deptno &par_ad;
Enter value for par_ad: desc

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

SQL> /
Enter value for par_ad: asc

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: To be pedantic, &-substitution is a feature of sqlplus/sqlcl/SQL Developer. If you are using a different client, this will probably not work.

Comment: @eaolson, the question was: "Is it possible?". The example I posted shows that it is possible. Right? :)

Comment: I can't use `&VAR` in my use case, only `:VAR`.